# Associate slider to a Float property

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I am working on an iOS project.
I have a `UISlider` on my ViewController.
I want to bind a Float property (var) to the current slider value.
If I change this property value, I want to automatically update my slider position.
If I move my slider, I want to automatically update property value.

I have made it work manually with delegates et stuff, but I want to know if there is a simplest way.
In fact, I have many (very huge) UISliders, and the values can change from other part of program.

I know in C# for example it is possible to observe a value and bind it with UI components. I want to do the same thing in swift

Comment: var myProgressFloat: CGFloat {
    didSet {
        self.progress = myProgressFloat
    }
}

Comment: I lied, you want the value to update on both occassions of you setting and receiving the variable you will need to use the get/set property attributes

Comment: `var myProgressFloat: CGFloat { 
    get { 
return slider.value } set(value) { slider.value = value} }`

Comment: I put all my UISlider in a TableView. What is the best way to access TableView Cell Rows's Sliders (One slider per row) from ViewController ? Thanks

Comment: create a custom UITableViewCell subclass and add an iboutlet to that and configure it in the storyboard

Comment: yes i have create a subclass and in can bind iboutlet to slider but the property is in the uitableviewcell subclass, not the viewcontroller

Comment: you can conform to the delegate of the slider with in the cell which then calls a custom delegate to the view controller. Things like value did change to value.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this and many libraries that help you with this task.

I like [Bond](https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond).

It lets you observe property values without the `didSet` boilerplate and helps you keep your code clean.

For example, this does exactly what you are looking for:

```
import Bond

let ageSlider = UISlider()
let age = Observable<Float>(0)
ageSlider.bnd_value.bidirectionalBindTo(age)
```

This helps you keeping the MVC or MVVM pattern, because changing the model property will also update the UI right away (and viceversa!):

```
age.Value = 18
print(ageSlider.value) // Prints 18
```

---

You can also combine values into a single one:

```
let slider1 = UISlider()
let slider2 = UISlider()
let averageValue = combineLatest(slider1.bnd_value, slider2.bnd_value).map{ (v1, v2) in (v1 + v2) / 2 }
averageValue.observe { newValue in
    print("New average value is \(newValue)")
}
```

More info in [the project page](https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond).